# Why does this code produce "syntax error, unexpected '='"?

Tags: php, string, concatenation, syntax-error, echo

```
$text . = '1 paragraph';
$text . = '2 paragraph';
$text . = '3 paragraph';
echo $text;
```

**This code gives error `syntax error, unexpected '='`.**

**What is the problem?**

Comment: there is no multiple data lines in this code. as well as no multiple variables to be merged into one. You'd better to explain in terms of natural language, not PHP ,what are you trying to achieve

Comment: *sigh and -1* You are aboard long enough to know that "doesn't work" is not a valid description of a problem.

Comment: @Happy I long removed my downvote since you added the error message.

Comment: I see Pekka daily on here on here giving great support to other programmers, there is a reason why SO built there system with down votes, Pekka's and other peoples decisions are good ones.

Comment: herd ran and destroyed the topic.

Comment: Well you're still blaming the herd, not yourself. No lesson has been learned. That selfish attitude is enough reason for downvotes.

Comment: Carrot lessons are better then the stick. Many people feel like they are gods, when make sense in small questions.

Comment: @Happy Looking at your 92 questions (many of which I have answered and given follow-up support on, too): Can *you* really complain about people treating you badly here?

Comment: @Pekka, I like the community, it gives a right support. Thanks for your answers too. That is the point.

Comment: @Happy that's all right, you're welcome. Just take care to always ask detailed questions in return, and everything's fine.

Comment: @Pekka, and the last note - I meant the people, who give minuses for a newbie questions, just because they are 'easy and funny', or for company.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want:

```
$text = '1 paragraph';
$text .= '2 paragraph';
$text .= '3 paragraph';
echo $text;
```

Note that the first line does not use `.=`, and just uses `=`

Answer (score 4):

The space between the dot and the equal? `.=` instead of `. =`

Comment: Happy, Are you sure the syntax error is coming form that command and not anywhere is, concatenation is the raw basics of programming and using the line Pekka stated WILL work.

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to output all of that anyway, then why concatenate at all? Just echo it:

```
echo '1 paragraph', 
     '2 paragraph',
     '3 paragraph';
```

Comment: comma(,) is faster than dot(.) for achieving concatenation in echo

Comment: @WebDeveloper Using `,` is not concatenating at all. It's just passing multiple arguments to `echo` and sending these directly to the output. When you use `.` you concatenate the arguments *before* passing them to `echo`. Whether you use `,` or `.` here is a µ-optimization not worth mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

Others have already pointed out the error: space between `.` and `=`.

This is a syntax/parse error. When PHP sees the `.` followed by space it takes `.` as a separate token which is used for string concatenation. Now it expects a string or a variable after it. But when it sees the `=` it throws the parse error as it does not match the PHP grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Also can echo like this

`echo '1 paragraph'.'2 paragraph'.'3 paragraph';`